Linux PCI iomem catch mem access errors in device driver
I have device on embedded CPU ls1043 running OS Linux (custom build on 4.14 kernel). CPU connected to FPGA with PCI 3.0 x1.
In FPGA only BAR 0 with all internal register space. But, not all addresses are valid. If address not valid, FPGA got timedout pci transaction. And ioread operation from CPU creates segfault.
AER don't catch this errors (wrong settings?). Can I handle errors in driver without segfault or range checks?

Why are you trying to read invalid addresses?

He's not really invalid. This address is in a valid address range, but it has “spaces” in it. Due to the complex development scheme of FPGA firmware and application software, sometimes synchronization problems occur and we want to catch them. And also to exclude the possibility of the kernel crashing in the release device due to errors, having the ability to capture errors

I'm confused.  Is the address valid or invalid?

The solution is for the FPGA to return a response to every read access in its address range, whether there is a register at that location or not. Trying to solve this in software is going to be fragile.

As @prl said, make default 0x00 or 0xFF return (with the respective bit width, if you support more than 32-bit accesses) on the absent registers. It should be fixed in RTL.
